# jQuery .click() function not working

Tags: jquery

I'm pretty sure my error is going to be obvious. I've been working for the last 6 hours and just can't find the brain power to figure where the hell I'm going wrong. If someone can let me know I'd really appreciate it.

Please note, I might commit suicide on finding out my error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#addCompanies").click(function() {
                alert("hello");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="addCompanies">Continue</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your DOM *ready* to be selected at the time of execution of that JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The handler passed to `.ready()` is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://d10ajoocuyu32n.cloudfront.net/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#addCompanies").click(function() {
                    alert("hello");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="addCompanies">Continue</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You sir are my saviour. I knew it would have been something stupid. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run this onLoad. Your code is trying to attach the click handler BEFORE the actual DOM element exists.

```
$(function(){
    $("#addCompanies").click(function() {
        alert("hello");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method to call a JavaScript function from a click is onclick try:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
alert("Hello World!");
}
</script>
<a id="addCompanies" onclick="myFunction()">Continue</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it inside on dom content ready:

```
$(function(){
    $("#addCompanies").click(function() {
                alert("hello");
            });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/RDxSV/